# Sshj library for download multifiles in remote server

Tags: file, java-8, download, remote-server, sshj

I use Java 8 and my condition is to download multiple file in a remote server using sftp protocol, is not necessary to filter file for his name but necessary to download all file in a specific remote folder.

i see the library com.hierynomus » sshj for this scope, but looking on the net i haven't found what i need, only for download a single file.

What i think is i could use this method,

```
String localDir = "/home";
String remoteFile = "/home/folder/*"
SSHClient sshClient = setupSshj();
SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();
sftpClient.get(remoteFile, localDir);
```

but i'm not sure if the asterisk in the *"remoteFile"* will be useful for my purpose...

Unfortunately for now i can't try this on remote server ...

Someone can help me?

Thank's everyone

Answer (score 1):

You need to LIST all the files you want to download:

```
List<RemoteResourceInfo> entries = sftpClient.ls("/home/folder")
```

After that you will loop the entries to download them one by one:

```
for (RemoteResourceInfo remoteFile : entries) {
    if(remoteFile.isRegularFile()){
        sftpClient.get(remoteFile.getPath(), localDir);
    }
}
```

E: Also you should check if the list entry is really a file, edited the code accordingly. Though I am not sure whether using `!remoteFile.isDirectory()` would be better.

Comment: Okkk thank's very much, that's what I needed!